# How to set Data into JNI and retrieve into java

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have some difficulties for the set data into JNI and get data into Java. How I can do? here please refer this code because what wrong with me I don’t know. please help me for this problem.


**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    public static native Student getStudentAge();

    protected Student student;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        student = getStudentAge();
        Log.d("TAG_DATA", String.valueOf(student.getAge()));
    }
}
```

**native-lib.cpp**

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_example_helloJni_MainActivity_getStudentAge(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {

    jclass fStdClass = env->FindClass("com/example/helloJni/Student");
    jobject nStdClass = env->AllocObject(fStdClass);
    jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(fStdClass, "setAge", "(I)V");
    env->CallObjectMethod(nStdClass, methodId, 10);

    return nStdClass;
}
```

**Error :**

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallObjectMethodV does not match
```

Comment: Please translate your incomprehensible question into English.

Comment: @EJP sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CallVoidMethod, because setAge returns void.